# removing jpegs metadata in android

Tags: android, image, compression, metadata, android-2.2-froyo

I have to compress an image (jpeg) in android application. While the compressing an image, does it strips out the metadata automatically? If not is there a way remove the metadata? Also is there any security concerns for the malicious metadata?

Comment: You don't have to compress a JPEG - it's already compressed ;) I presume you know that and just misspoke. So, what is your source and destination image data? You can always load a JPEG and write it's bitmap data to a new JPEG. Since bitmap data doesn't have metadata included, you have the guarantee that it'll be stripped.

Comment: Thanks man. I just wanted an answer for metadata. You helped me out. So that means if I just convert jpeg to png it will not have any metadata associated with it?

Comment: Generally yes, PNG doesn't support metadata information like JPEG (eg EXIF). But other formats may support it. However if you'll just read *image* data (ie. bitmap pixel values) and save them in arbitrary format, you'll loose all metadata information.

Comment: Thanks andr. Its help full. But do you know why exactly does that happens? Why does an image on the time of conversion looses all the meta data?

Comment: It's simply a matter of the file format. Look at it like that: an image is like a book and *one* of the pages is its pixel data. When you take out *that* page and throw away the others (that's essentially what you're doing when you copy the bitmap data), what do you end up with? Only this one single page - you have thrown away (discarded) the rest.